# No SSH connection possible over Wi-Fi

Tags: macos, network, wifi, ssh

I have a MacBook Pro from 2014 running macOS Mojave. I cannot SSH into a remote server, use git over SSH or use the Mac App Store while connected to my Wi-Fi at home. Some of my mail accounts seem to have a problem, others work.

There is no problem with other devices, there is no problem if I am connected over Ethernet, there is no problem if I am connected via a different Wi-Fi, there is no problem if I use my university VPN via Wi-Fi, and there is no problem if I am running Ubuntu via USB.

The problem seems to be a specific combination from Home Wi-Fi and my macOS. I don't really want to reinstall my OS, and I don't have a single clue what I can do or try.

DNS-Servers are:

- 8.8.8.8

and

- 8.8.4.4

for IPv4, and

- 2001:4860:4860::8888
- 2001:4860:4860::8844

for IPv6.

Comment: Could it be a DNS issue, perhaps? What happens if you go to System Preferences > Network and unlock it, hit Advanced in the bottom right, and add `1.1.1.1` and `1.0.0.1` over in DNS?

Comment: I forgot to mention that, DNS-Servers are `8.8.8.8`, and `8.8.4.4` for IPv4, and `2001:4860:4860::8888` , `2001:4860:4860::8844` for IPv6, although I don't have IPv6. Adding those DNS-Servers you mentioned and flushing the DNS-Cache has no effect.

Comment: When you say "cannot SSH", what do you mean, more exactly? Do you get any error messages? What is the output if you add the -v option (verbose) to the ssh command?

Comment: The output:
`OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/***/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ***.com port 22.`
And after that, nothing happens, so no error output, it seems like nothing is happening at all

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to network segmentation.

What type of gateway/router are you using?

Is it possible that you are connecting to a guest type network, or that the gateway has a network segmentation feature which is turned on?

Comment: I am using the router I got from the Internet-Provider, it is called EasyBox 804, I am using the normal network, and there is no guest network activated :/